# Prevent illustrator layer color over text being edited

Tags: adobe-illustrator

When editing text in Illustrator, the text being edited receives a solid overlay of the colour of the layer it belongs.

This is sometimes annoying, as I would like to see the text with its own colour and effects.

How can I prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is probably better suited for http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com. In the future, I'd recommend searching for answers and posting questions there. However, I understand that doesn't help you as quickly, so to answer your current question...
Under the **View** menu, you'll want to play with **Hide Edges** and **Hide Bounding Box**, depending on exactly what you're trying to accomplish, you may have to turn off both.

### Bounding Box

The **Bounding Box** refers to a single perimeter around the furthest boundary of all currently selected objects. This also contains the transform controls/handles that can be seen at each corner, and in the middle of each side of the perimeter box. This does not affect the highlighting of individual object edges within the selection.

### Edges

The **Edges** refers to the edges of each object within the current selection. If any of the objects are text objects, it also refers to the underlining within the text box.
It's worth noting that if you only have one object selected, you'll notice very little difference unless you choose to hide both **Edges** and **Bounding Box**.

Comment: I've played with both options and I understand their meaning, but I still see only the solid color of the layer over my texts.

Comment: Maybe also try making sure `View > Smart Guides` is not checked? I can't imagine what else would be making it show the layer color over the text. If that doesn't resolve it, could you please provide a screenshot?

Comment: That is a solution. Smart Guides off solved my 'problem'. Thanks a lot.